# Confused by the HtmlHelper<TModel>.RadioButtonFor<TResult>(...) docs

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

So, I'm reading the actual docs for `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` at [HtmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(...) docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.htmlhelper-1.radiobuttonfor?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and it says "*Adds a "checked" attribute to the element if value matches the first non-null value found in: the htmlAttributes dictionary entry with key "checked", or the ModelState entry with full name.*"

Basically, it appears that I need someone to explain that sentance to me because I'm following it to the best of my ability and 'checked' is never rendered!

Now, under the right conditions, this helper is called, and if I'm not mistaken, the 'value' is set from `Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].SelectedAnswer`, and that value is also specified as the @checked entry in my htmlAttributes, yet, I get no `checked` in my markup!

```
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(
        model => model.IDProofingQuestions[i].SelectedAnswerId,
        Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].SelectedAnswer,
        new
        {
            @class = "radio radio-button",
            @checked = Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].SelectedAnswer,
            @onclick = "updateBoolean( " +
                selectedAnswerId + ", " + selectedAnswerIdId + ", " +
                Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].PaId + " )"
        })
```

And here's the rendered element.

```
<input class="radio radio-button"
  id="IDProofingQuestions_0__SelectedAnswerId" name="IDProofingQuestions[0].SelectedAnswerId" 
  onclick="updateBoolean( 'IDProofingQuestions_0__PossibleAnswers_1__SelectedAnswer', 'IDProofingQuestions_0__SelectedAnswerId', 2 )" type="radio" value="True">
```

I'm thinking that this should be all the info you need dear reader, but if I've not provided enough, please let me know and I'll add whatever might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

> that value is also specified as the @checked entry in my htmlAttributes, yet, I get no checked in my markup!

It is a [known github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3098#issuecomment-138049453). You've provided an `expression` and a `value` to compare it against. That comparison always overrides a `checked` value from `htmlAttributes`. Other `htmlAttributes` values are visible in the generated HTML.

That is to say, only if the value of `model.IDProofingQuestions[i].SelectedAnswerId` **equals** to the value of `Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].SelectedAnswer`, can the `checked` work.

Comment: Any chance you know how to make this happen? And by this I mean using a RadioButtonFor within nested for loops to show already-selected radio buttons?

Comment: I think you may do not read my answer carefully. Get the value of `model.IDProofingQuestions[i].SelectedAnswerId` and 
 `Model.IDProofingQuestions[i].PossibleAnswers[paIdx].SelectedAnswer` in your backend code then return them(`return View(model)`). If they have the same value, the radio button will be checked. If they have different value, the radio button will be unchecked.

Comment: well, unfortunately those are two different types. `int` & `bool` I ended up moving away from the tag helpers and coding my `id`'s and `name`s myself and finally got it working.